# How to divide Cytoscape circle nodes into several pieces

Tags: cytoscape.js

[image: cytoscape_network]

I have import a network from file in cytoscape like the picture above. But i want to divide the circles into several pieces like a pie chart.

I have find the [cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/#introduction/factsheet) which seem to do this, but it's difficult to me. I expect the result to be similar to the image below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @wanghao, can you please explain, what your current approach is and also add your code as an executable snippet? That way we can do much more for you. Also, please clarify which part of the process you are having trouble with. The way you asked your question now is quite open to interpret and that is not ideal. The answer now would be to follow the code from [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/tree/master/documentation/demos/pie-style).Thank you :D

Comment: Hi, sorry for delaying two days to reply. I'm not familiar with java, so i use the Cytoscape in Windows platform to create a network diagram. Now, I just want do this: the nodes need to be divided into three parts in order to reflect the attributes of these nodes with three colors, which seems like a pie chart. I don't know if the cytoscape.js can do this in a simple way, or there's other ways. Thank you so much to help me!